# Registro en Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, firebase

Estoy desarrollando una *app* en *Android*, y tengo pensado implementar mensajes descendentes, el inconveniente es obtener un *token* válido para el registro en *FCM*.

Si bien, sé que obtener el *token* de esta forma es correcta...

```
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm= GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance( context);
String regid=  gcm.register(SENDER_ID  );
```

... está obsoleta. ¿Existe otra forma de registrar pero para la nueva versión?

Answer (score 1):

Pues la forma que uso yo con FCM es poniendo en la MainActivity:

```
if (FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()== null)
{
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");
}
```

Y luego en la clase que extiende `FirebaseInstanceIdService` lo siguiente:

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    // [START refresh_token]
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
                        // Get updated InstanceID token.
            String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
            Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

                new regInServer().execute(refreshedToken);
    }
    // [END refresh_token]
```

Además no te tienes que olvidar de incluir los servicios en el Manifest:

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Y no se si se me olvida algo, pero espero que te valga con eso.